# Control ASDoc Tooltips in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, actionscript, flash-builder, asdoc

In Eclipse (w/ Flash Builder 4.6) if you add ASDocs to your Actionscript the tooltip for that class/method/property will include that ASDoc and use the tags to do some formatting. Is there a way to change how it formats as well as add tags for it to use?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of tags that can be used.

[ASDoc tags](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=asdoc_1.html)

Then you can use the ASDoc tool to export them into full HTML documents, which all come from your comments, and appear the same as they do in the tooltips within Flex.

Comment: Useful link but what I'm looking for is a way to get Eclipse to show more tags and/or change how it does show the tags it currently shows.